# How can i load an xml column in sql server to dataGridView c#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, datagridview, ado.net

I have a table with a Column XML type named XMLContent.
When I load this table into DataGridView I see all columns without XMLContent (the column is empty in the DataGridView). How can I do to fix this?

This is my C# code:

```cs
using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    sqlconnection.Open();
        
    string query = "Select * from RAP_HISTO_FIC_MAT order by FicName ASC";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconnection))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            SqlParameter xmlColum = new SqlParameter();

            DataTable records = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(records);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = records;

            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        }
    }
    sqlconnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `records` actually has data in the column? Put a break point on the line… `dataGridView1.DataSource = records;` … and examine what `records` contains.

Comment: yes and the dataGridView1 contain the table but the XMLContent  is empty

Comment: So, all the data IS in the `records` table, but when you set the grids data source using the `records` table some columns are empty in the grid but the data exist in the `records` table? Can you give an example of what the records table looks like? Also, what do you mean by `XMLContnet`? Technically, XML is just a `string` and it sounds like you may need some further conversion of the XML data, but this is a guess.

Comment: yes exactly , how can i display an XML type in dataGridView1 ? i want to display a link of an XML to open it later

Comment: A “link” and an XML file are two different things. What is returned from the DB? Show what `records` contains?

Comment: @JohnG i have a column in sql server with xml type i need a conversion to this column to be displayed in dataGridView1 car actually it's empty

Comment: I will assume the column is a “link” column … and I am pretty sure that the grid will NOT “automatically” convert that column to a “Link” column. You will have to add a `DataGridViewLinkColumn` to the grid in code or the designer. Note: You will need to set the columns `DataPropertyName` to point to the link column in the table. In addition, you will need to add the link column to the grid BEFORE you set the grids data source.

Comment: ok than you ....